# how to find between dates in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I give two different date as a input. i want to find, what are date between two date..

For eg:

```
1'st Input is :  2011-02-20 

2'nd input is :  2011-02-25

   Output is:
             2011-02-20
             2011-02-21
             2011-02-22
             2011-02-23
             2011-02-24
             2011-02-25
```

Is there any function to find the between date...

otherwise how to find ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CTE to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate    DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2011-02-20'
SET @EndDate = '2011-02-25'

;WITH GetDates AS
(
SELECT 1 as counter, @StartDate AS Date
UNION ALL
SELECT counter + 1, DATEADD( day, counter, @StartDate )
FROM GetDates
WHERE DATEADD( day, counter, @StartDate ) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT Date FROM GetDates
```

Comment: Minor tweak needed - change "SELECT 0 as counter" to SELECT 1... instead, else you get the first date returned twice.

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

> A calendar table can make it much
>   easier to develop solutions around any
>   business model which involves dates.
>   Last I checked, this encompasses
>   pretty much any business model you can
>   think of, to some degree.    Constant
>   problems that end up requiring
>   verbose, complicated and inefficient
>   methods include the following
>   questions: How many business days
>   between x and y?  ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date = @StartDate + number
  FROM master..spt_values
 WHERE type = 'P'
   AND number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Note: This solution is not applicable when the distance between the two dates is more than 2047 days.